# How to track screen names in firebase analytics using beamer?

Tags: flutter, firebase-analytics, flutter-beamer

I'm pretty fresh to beamer and navigator 2.0 so this may be a newbie question.

I have included a `FirebaseAnalyticsObserver` as an observer in my `BeamerDelegate` but my firebase analytics dashboard still doesn't recognize screen names. All screen names are 'not set'.

Traditionally, screen names used be passed in via the RouteSettings in Nav 1.0, and firebase analytics would track them appropriately.

How are screen names set (for this purpose) within the beamer framework?

Any tips on what I'm missing would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `name` property on every `BeamPage` to see the names displayed in Firebase Analytics using `FirebaseAnalyticsObserver.`